# De Bruijn tori in higher dimensions?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

> ***Q***. Do there exist De Bruijn tori in dimension $d > 2$?

A [De Bruijn torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_torus)
is a two-dimensional generalization of a 
[De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).
A De Bruijn sequence is, for two symbols,
a cyclical bit-string that contains all bit strings of length $n$
as consecutive, left-to-right bits (with wrap-around).
For example, here is a sequence of $8$ bits that contains all $2^3$ bit
strings of length $3$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & \color{red}{0}  & \color{red}{0}  & \color{red}{1} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0}  & \color{red}{1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0}  & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$

Here is a De Bruijn torus that includes all $2 \times 2$ bit-matrices 
exactly once (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_torus#/media/File:2-2-4-4-de-Bruijn-torus.svg)):
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
$$
A $4 \times 4$ De Bruijn torus has been explicitly constructed.

My question is: Is it known that there exist 
De Bruijn tori in dimensions larger than $d=2$?
Perhaps for every dimension?
For example, a three-dimensional pattern of bits that includes
every $k \times k \times k$ bit-(hyper)matrix?

Comment: Did you code $d=2$ as d{=}2 on purpose, or were you using one of those software packages that writes the code for you? I looked at it and the fact that it had less space before and after the "equals" sign was conspicuous, so then I looked at how it was coded. Those packages sometimes write code that looks as if a lunatic wrote it (although this instance is not that extreme).

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I wrote d{=}2 on purpose, but it is fine to retain your edit.

Comment: What purpose was intended to be served by writing it that way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. See ["New constructions for de Bruijn tori" by Hurlbert and Isaak](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01390770)

Comment: Thanks! Here's a [PDF link](http://www.lehigh.edu/~gi02/ncnsfv.pdf), perhaps a draft of the journal article to which you link.